# Javascript Change the parent text color via button child

Tags: javascript, html

I want to append a button to any divs with the class name "colors". When the button is clicked the Parent's (of the clicked button) text color will change to the desired color.
It only changes the last element.

Here's what I have so far.
https://codepen.io/i-empty/pen/mdpLNEB

```js
var colors = document.querySelectorAll('.colors');

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
 var btn = document.createElement('button'); 
  btn.classList.add('button');
  btn.textContent = "Change";

  colors[i].append(btn);
  
}
  btn.addEventListener("click", ChangeColor);

// Change Colors
function ChangeColor() {
  for (var _ = 0; _ < colors.length; _++) {
    colors[_].style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 10px;
  float: right; 
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
}
.colors {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
 
}
```

```html
  <div class="colors">Hi</div>
  <div class="colors">Hello</div>
  <div class="colors">Goodbye</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some minor changes not really required but the most important one was adding the event handler, to the newly created button element, **inside the loop** and not only once at the end. That's why only your last button was triggering the event changing the colors.

Here's my solution:

```js
let colors;

//init the gui once the document was loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  colors = document.querySelectorAll('.colors');
  init();
});

//Init the gui
function init(){ 
  //loop through the .colors divs
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    //add a new button to the current div
    let btn = document.createElement('button'); 
    btn.classList.add('button');
    btn.textContent = "Change";
    btn.addEventListener("click", ChangeColor);
    colors[i].append(btn);
  }
}

//Change text color to all .colors divs
function ChangeColor(event) {
  color = event.target.parentNode;
  if (color.style.color == "red")
      color.style.color = "black";
  else
      color.style.color = "red";
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 10px;
  float: right; 
 }
 
&:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

&:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.colors {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">Hi</div>
<div class="colors">Hello</div>
<div class="colors">Goodbye</div>
```

Comment: This changes colour for all the divs, not just the colour of the div whose button was clicked.

Comment: you used a for loop div to make that function.. it didn't make sense but if you put so much efforts maybe there was a reason. No it was nonsense :D Ok I'll correct that part

Comment: the final update implements a logic where the button triggers changing color only on its own div. If you click it again it reverts to its previous color.

Answer (score 0):

Pick up your buttons. Add event listeners to all of them, and then when the function is called find the element's parent node and add a new class to it.

```js
const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.colors');

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.classList.add('button');
  btn.textContent = "Change";
  colors[i].append(btn);
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', changeColor, false);
});

// Change Colors
function changeColor() {
  this.parentNode.classList.add('red');
}
```

```css
.button{background-color:red;color:#fff;padding:5px 10px;border-radius:5px;bottom:10px;float:right}
.colors{padding:10px;border:1px solid #000;border-radius:5px;width:55%;margin:10px 0;font-size:20px;font-weight:700;font-family:Sans-serif}
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<div class="colors">Hi</div>
<div class="colors">Hello</div>
<div class="colors">Goodbye</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var colors = document.querySelectorAll('.colors');

const ChangeColor = event => {
    if (event.target.parentNode.style.color === "red") {
    
event.target.parentNode.style.color = "black"
    } else {
event.target.parentNode.style.color =  "red"
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
 var btn = document.createElement('button'); 
  btn.classList.add('button');
  btn.textContent = "Change";

  colors[i].append(btn);
  
  btn.addEventListener("click", ChangeColor);
}
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 10px;
  float: right; 
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
}
.colors {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
 
}
```

```html
  <div class="colors">Hi</div>
  <div class="colors">Hello</div>
  <div class="colors">Goodbye</div>
```